# Kotlin DSL does not see function

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have the below

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url = uri(System.getenv("COLIBRIO_MAVEN_URL")
                ?: getLocalProperty("COLIBRIO_MAVEN_URL")
            )
            credentials {
                username = System.getenv ("COLIBRIO_MAVEN_USERNAME")
                    ?: getLocalProperty("COLIBRIO_MAVEN_USERNAME") as String
                password = System.getenv ("COLIBRIO_MAVEN_PASSWORD")
                    ?: getLocalProperty("COLIBRIO_MAVEN_PASSWORD") as String
            }
        }
    } 
    // ...
}

fun getLocalProperty(key: String): Any {
    val properties = java.util.Properties()
    val localProperties = File("local.properties")
    if (localProperties.isFile) {
        java.io.InputStreamReader(java.io.FileInputStream(localProperties), Charsets.UTF_8).use { reader ->
            properties.load(reader)
        }
    } else error("File from not found")

    return properties.getProperty(key)
}
```

And I get `Unresolved reference: getLocalProperty` on the line with `?: getLocalProperty("COLIBRIO_MAVEN_URL")`. Why is that? Why does it not see the `getLocalProperty` function?